# Working on maven multi-module project in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, module, project, m2e

I am creating my first hierarchical multi-module project in Eclipse:

```
 /project
    pom.xml
      (...)
      <groupId>a.b.c</groupId>
      <artifactId>myProject</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <packaging>pom</packaging>
      <modules>
        <module>x</module>
        <module>y</module>
      </modules>
    /x
      pom.xml
        (...)
        <parent>
          <artifactId>myProject</artifactId>
          <groupId>a.b.c</groupId>
          <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </parent>    
      /src
      .project
    /y
      pom.xml
        (...)
        <parent>
          <artifactId>myProject</artifactId>
          <groupId>a.b.c</groupId>
          <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </parent>    
      /src
      .project
```

Ideally, I would like to see in my Eclipse workspace three folders:

```
  /project
    pom.xml
  /x
    pom.xml
    src
    .project
  /y
    pom.xml
    src
    .project
```

- x and y would find the parent pom.xml in the project folder.  I would be able to work on them independently as maven projects.
- project would only contain the parent pom.xml

At least that's my intuition on how it would be practical to work on this project.

I committed my code in SVN and I can get close to that structure by doing an SVN checkout using option "Find projects in the children of the selected resource" (available as long as there is not a .project in the parent project folder).  This creates projects x and y in my workspace, but I get compilation errors because of the missing parent pom.xml.  I can get rid of these errors by putting the parent pom.xml in the workspace on its own, but that doesn't seem a clean solution.

I suppose that one solution to my problem would be to flatten my structure some and create a 'parent' folder at the same level as x and y and my parent pom.xml and a .project file in there, but it seems odd to have to put the parent at the same level as the child just for the sake of making Eclipse happy.  The closest to an answer that I found online is http://warpedjavaguy.wordpress.com/2011/08/08/how-i-defeated-the-maven-release-plugin-in-a-flat-structured-multi-module-project/, which seems to approach the problem in a similar way.

Is there a better approach that I am missing?

PS: I have m2e.

Comment: Which version of Eclipse? m2e installed ?

Comment: m2e installed, yes. I have Juno.

Answer (score 0):

I think I am answering my own question here.

- I checked out the project outside of Eclipse.
- Then I Imported as a maven project

I got exactly the view I expected: i.e. 4 folders in my workspace(one for the parent and 3 for each of the children).  Somehow, I recall there was an option to do exactly this in one step (i.e. checkout and import) with my previous version of Eclipse.  It was called "Check out as maven project" and it seems to have disappeared with Juno.  Or perhaps I am missing the correct plugin (I  have m2e installed as well as Subversive; it could be that another svn plugin does that instead of subversive).